# Unrecognized folder icon - Sublime Text 3

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

I created a folder from the Sublime folder view (Right Click - New Folder) and it has a different icon than other folders. What does this icon mean?

- I have created a lot of new folders from Sublime and they all had the default icon.
- If i create a new folder under Model (sibling to Checkout), or as a child of Checkout it gets the same unrecognized icon. If i create a new folder in any other place, it gets the default icon.

I use Sublime Text 3 (Material Theme), and Fedora 24

The unrecognized icon in the following screenshot, is "Checkout" folder's icon.

[image: Unrecognized icon in Sublime Folder View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon is https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme/blob/0d86523a4ec71e32f4ca1a06e38bb3be63a202ea/assets/default/folder_dup.png, which we can see from the theme is used for symlinks: https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme/blob/431b28cc4f7d20878bc85dc81762bfaf29301e0c/Material-Theme.sublime-theme#L823-L830

> ```
> // Symlink folder icon
> {
>   "class": "icon_folder_dup",
>   "layer0.texture": "Material Theme/assets/default/folder_dup.png",
>   "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
>   "content_margin": [11, 7]
> },
> ```

More detail is given in the [official Theme documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#elements-side_bar):

> Used for a folder that has been scanned previously in the sidebar. *This is necessary to prevent a possibly infinite list of files due to recursive symlinks.*